# Find the Max/Min of values within a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I've searched for answers to this specific question, but haven't been able to find anything. I need to find the maximum and minimum of the input numbers but the values I need are inside the for loop and I can't figure out how to use them outside of it.

```
System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to input?");

    int totalNumbers = console.nextInt();

    int minMax = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= totalNumbers; i++){
        System.out.print("Number " + i + ": ");
        int inputNumbers = console.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println();

    int smallest = Math.min(minMax);
    System.out.println("Smallest = " + smallest);
    int largest = Math.max(minMax); 
    System.out.println("Largest = " + largest);
```

I don't need changed code just something that will get me on the right track.Thank you!

Comment: Consider to collect input numbers into temporary data structure like array or collection which you can analyse later out of collecting loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you notice the problem with the following loop?

```
for(int i = 1; i <= totalNumbers; i++){
        System.out.print("Number " + i + ": ");
        int inputNumbers = console.nextInt();
    }
```

You are running the loop `totalNumbers` times and every time you create a new `int` with name `inputNumbers` and store the value received from console. Also where are you changing the value of `minMax`? Also `Math.min(or max)` does not take single paramtere and wont even compile.

Now you have few options:

1. Either store all the numbers in an array and then traverse that for min and max elements using some utility method.
2. Set some min and max value and run a loop to get all items and also keep track of min and max in loop.

I am not writing any solution as I want you to try it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The Math.min() and Math.max() methods, according to the oracle documentation, can only compare two values. Importing the values into an array, and then performing operations on the array, should allow you to find minimums and maximums, as well as any other data operation quite easily.

```
int[] numbers = new int[totalNumbers];

for (int i = 0; i < totalNumbers; i++) {
    numbers[i] = console.nextInt();
}

//Other Operations
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm misreading what you want, can't you just maintain a variable on the outside of the for loop and check them?

```
int minMax = 0;
int smallest = 0;
int largest = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= totalNumbers; i++){
    System.out.print("Number " + i + ": ");
    int inputNumbers = console.nextInt();
    if(inputNumbers > largest){
        largest = inputNumbers;
    } else if (inputNumbers < smallest){
        smallest = inputNumbers;
   }
}
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Smallest = " + smallest);
System.out.println("Largest = " + largest);
```

This is the most direct and logical way of checking the input values and deciding whether they're the smallest or largest currently known (**Edit:** Unless you *require* the use of `Math.minMax`)

Comment: This approach is clean, but your initial values are problematic. (-1)

Comment: @DaoWen I agree, to some extent. Either I'd need to double-check the values against some kind of constant value, or initialize `smallest` to the max int size, and `largest` to the min int size. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode:

```
smallest := +∞
largest  := -∞

for each number read, n:
    if n > largest:
        largest := n
    if n < smallest:
        smallest := n

print the results
```

Hint:

Java `int`s can't represent ±∞. Use [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) and [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) instead.

Comment: No `Integer` can be smaller than `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and no `Integer` can be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and in that case we will always get `smallest` and `largest` as the result. Nope?

Comment: @akhil_mittal - If you're not careful with the initial values, then you might end up with garbage at the end. E.g., if the user enters all positive numbers, but `smallest` was initialized to `0`, then that code will return `0` as the `smallest`, even though the user never entered `0`. By using the max value for `smallest` and the min value for `largest`, you guarantee that the final results will be from the user input (as long as the user enters at least one number).

Comment: In case user entered values as `10,50,40,30,60` the output will not be `10 and 60`.  Isn't it?

Comment: @akhil_mittal - I'm not sure what you're asking... The smallest is 10, and the largest is 60. [Here's a demo of my pseudocode in JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/DaoWen/7d9bq2dv/).

Comment: Oh yea. I just got confused :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by just put if else condition inside for loop... like

1. take 2 variable at outside loop one for max value and other for min value store.
2. inside loop assign input number to min and max first time.
3. after that comare next number with this and reassign values.
4. at end of loop you will find both min and max.