# Finding the maximum value from a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have created code that gives me thousands of solutions when looking for palindromic numbers. The task is to find the highest number possible:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        long product;
        outer: for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
            for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--) {
                product = j * i;
                if (reverse(product)) {
                    System.out.printf("%d * %d = %d%n", i, j, product);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static final boolean reverse(long value) {
        String str = String.valueOf(value);
        return str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
    }}
```

How can I make it so that the code only displays the highest value that the for loop creates?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS not necessarily, if the highest is 998,998, and 999,900 is a palindrome, that won't work

Comment: @RobinTopper at which point should the break outer be implemented?

Comment: @RobinTopper yes I just tried it and it just gave me the first value. Thank you for helping though.

Comment: @HarryOrson I think you should accept [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43740029/7598776) instead of mine, since I only implemented his proposed solution

Comment: [How do I get the max and min values from a set of numbers entered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671453/how-do-i-get-the-max-and-min-values-from-a-set-of-numbers-entered) [Find the Max/Min of values within a for loop.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073179/find-the-max-min-of-values-within-a-for-loop)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution decribed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43740029/7598776) in code:

```
long highest_palindrome = 0L;
int storeI = 0;
int storeJ = 0;
long product;
outer: for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
    for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--) {
        product = j * i;
        if (product < highest_palindrome) break;
        if (reverse(product)) {
            if (product > highest_palindrome) {
                highest_palindrome = product;
                storeI = i;
                storeJ = j;
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
}

System.out.printf("%d * %d = %d%n", storeI, storeJ, highest_palindrome);
```

Comment: If the downvoters could also leave a comment with a reason/explanation, you'd make me very happy

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier If you're talking about [this comment of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739858/finding-the-maximum-value-from-a-for-loop/43740029#comment74523066_43740041), this code [does print `993 * 913 = 906609`](http://ideone.com/6XIzUV).

Answer (score 1):

Save your product for a later comparison.
If you found a palindrom compare it to the last highest palindrom. If it is higher than the saved value store the new value as last highest palindrom. Store the according i and j values also.
At the end of the loops just print the last highest palindrom and its i and j values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cents.

While other answers contain valid code which actually solves the problem, there is a severe performance hit with them.

### Don't use `StringBuilder.reverse()`

To check if a string is a palindrome, the reverse method of the `StringBuilder` is often used. It creates a new `StringBuilder` object, copies the characters of a string and puts them in reverse order. Then a `String` instance is retrieved and compared against the original string.
This approach has two implications:

- A StringBuilder object is created for each palindrome check.
- Each character of the two strings are checked agains eachother.

You are better off comparing the first character against the last character, the second character against the second-last character, et cetera. You only have to check the first half, the second half is already matched against the first half of the string.

So the palindrome checker function would be as follows:

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It's roughly seven times faster than using `reverse()`.

### Don't try to match `b` against `a` if `a` against `b` is already checked

This snippet looks okay, but it isn't:

```
for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
    for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It takes twice as long to check all combinations, for if `a` is checked against `b`, you don't have to check `b` against `a`. The following snippet tackles this:

```
for (int i = 999; i > 100; i--) {
    for (int j = i; j > 100; j--) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It simply stores `i` into `j`, so `j` starts with the value of `i`.

### Code

So you'd better use this code:

```
private static void checkNumbers() {

    long max = 0;
    long a = 0;
    long b = 0;
    int lowerBounds = 0;

    for (int i = 999; i > lowerBounds; i--) {
        for (int j = i; j > lowerBounds ; j--) {
            long product = i * j;

            // Check if the product is already smaller than our found
            // maximum. If that's the case, than any value of j lower
            // than the current value of j will always be smaller than
            // the currently found value.
            if (product <= max) {
                break;
            }
            else if (isPalindrome(String.valueOf(product))) {
                max = product;
                a = i;
                b = j;
                // If we found a match, then this is the least of the two
                // products of our result. We don't have to go any lower
                // than j.
                lowerBounds = j;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max);
    System.out.println(a + " * " + b);
}

private static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It's at least 15 times faster than the accepted answer.

*Note that there are more ways to improve the performance. For instance, you can store the least of both factors found, and then both `i` and `j` don't have to go any lower. For example: if we found for `i` the value `995` and for `j` the value `583`, we don't have to go any lower than `583`.*

Answer (score 0):

As you are starting your iteration from the biggest number to smallest number

```
for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--)
```

The first palindrome number which you will get will be the greatest palindrome number.

You will get the result in desending order.

Comment: Not true, look at the results: 995 * 583 = 580085 / 995 * 517 = 514415 / 993 * 913 = 906609

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED CODE TO GET YOUR REQUIREMENT NOW IT WILL PRINT ONLY GREATEST PALINDROME NUMBER ONLY**

You get product as your palindrome number so create an **array-list** and push your result in it as

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        long product;
       ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
        outer: for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
            for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--) {
                product = j * i;
                if (reverse(product)) {
                    System.out.printf("%d * %d = %d%n", i, j, product);
                    al.add(product);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
   Collections.sort(al, Collections.reverseOrder());
// System.out.println("ArrayList in descending order:");
      System.out.println("The Greatest number is "+al.get(0));

    }
```

**Here you will get all values in descending order and so the first element will be the greatest palindrome number**

Comment: This code prints every palindrom found. The question is about only printing the highest one. Collecting all palindroms found is also unnecessary if you only need the highest one.

Comment: so if you don't want to print all the numbers just remove the for loop that prints all the array-list value remove for statement and instead of  System.out.println(str); write  System.out.println(al.get(0));  I will post the updated answer again here

Comment: its simple dear just remove all system.out .println statement except last.

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long product;
        long max=0;
        outer: for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
            for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--) {
                product = j * i;
                if (reverse(product)) {
                    if(product>max)
                     {  max=product;
                        break;
                     }
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
       System.out.printf("%d",max);
    }
    private static final boolean reverse(long value) {
        String str = String.valueOf(value);
        return str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
    }}
```

What i have done is, just keep a variable max, then whenever you find a palindrome, check whether it is larger than the max, if yes then set max=product. 
So, finally you get the maximum palindrome number.
**Note:** Observe the `break` statement. I have used it because whenever you find a max palindrome, then other palindrome with the same first number will be smaller than this palindrome. So you can directly move to the next first number.